# Having multiple IFrames in a single page

Tags: html, iframe

I have an application which takes in users' HTML from an editor like CKEditor and display them back to the user in a list.

To be safe, as in to avoid breaking the container page's html structure by mal-formed html input, i want to render each user's html input in an iframe (iframe will render from a URL).

The container page will just have a list of frames each with users html. They will be sized to a height of 100px or so to accommodate multiple inputs in a list.

My question is:

1.) how good of an idea is it to render potentially hundreds of iFrames in a single page ? Will the memory usage blow-up the end users browser ?

2.) Is there a safer and easier way to render user's html ? I want to put as few restrictions as possible on user's input.

[I will of course sanitize all the input on the server before sending it back to client.]

Answer (score 0):

The iFrame is exactly what you are looking for.

Why would you render 100+ iFrames? As I understood, you want to paste the content of a users "page" to your page - so just make it one site per "user Site" ...

If you want to display all iFrames on one site, it would be a potential huge ass Website but as everying is static, it should'nt be a problem.

Comment: Think of it like stack overflow or a forum, when u r replying, you are entering HTML. in a thread, there could be hundreds of replies. my use-case is somewhat similar. I am not sure what you mean by one site per user site..

Comment: I thought about something like JSBin (which is also made with iFrames) but in a forum you can limit the iFrames per Site by limitting the answers per page.